# Symfony container has no extensions when loading my bundle

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

I have a bundle which was working quite well for some time. However, I had to add some custom configuration params to it, so I wrote some lines in the bundle's config.yml, something like this:

```
# ...
acme_my_bundle:
    special_params: ['param_1', 'param_2']
```

The configuration is defined in the bundle's `Configuration` class:

```
namespace ACME\MyBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

/**
 * This is the class that validates and merges configuration from your app/config files
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#cookbook-bundles-extension-config-class}
 */
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder() {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('acme_my_bundle');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('special_params')
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

The bundle is properly registered in `AppKernel.php`:

```
public function registerBundles() {
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new ACME\MyBundle(),
        // ...
    );

    // ...

    return $bundles;
}
```

However, when I try to use my app, I get an error:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "acme_my_bundle" (in (path_to_bundle)/MyBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "acme_my_bundle", found none
```

I looked it up, but most results found were unsatisfactory - I eliminated the problems that came up during searching:

- improper configuration structure
- bundle not registered in the app kernel
- config root node name different than the one returned from `ACMEMyBundleExtension::getAlias()`

I tried debugging the cause of the exception being thrown and discovered that when the YAML file loader tries to validate my config file, the container has no extensions:

```
var_dump($container->getExtensions()); // prints empty array - array(0) { }
```

It causes the validation to fail and the *none* part of the message to be displayed - there a no available extensions.

I tried debugging `$this->extensions` in `ContainerBuilder::hasExtension()` and for some reason the list is complete when the method is launched for the vendor bundles, but is empty for my bundle. It looks like that something in my bundle is still defined or registered incorrectly.

<sub>I changed the names off classes, etc. not to expose company code, excuse me for that if it causes confusion.</sub>

**EDIT:** I didn't explicitly mention it, but the `Extension` class is defined and the exception occurs when it is loaded - just as I have written above:

> when the YAML file loader tries to validate my config file

To be more clear, here is my `Extension` class:

```
namespace ACME\MyBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class ACMEMyBundleExtension extends Extension {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        // The exception is thrown here
        $loader->load('config.yml');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your configuration reader in `ACME\MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration` for `$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('BUNDLE_CONFIG_KEY');`.

`BUNDLE_CONFIG_KEY` should be:

- valid (same in `ACME\MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration` and your `config.yml`
- unique for the app

Also please check you're defining bundle configuration in correct way - it should be added to `app/config/*.yml` (one of global config files). Maybe you have added `acme_my_bundle` config in other custom bundle config files?

Comment: And that was it! I added the configuration in the local bundle `config.yml`, what a silly mistake...

Answer (score 1):

You have missed bundle extension class (ACME\MyBundle\DependencyInjection\ACMEMyExtension) as explained here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html. Cookbook entry for bundle configuration is [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html). Key in config.yml should be named only as acme_my.

Comment: The `Extension` is defined, I have updated my question to specifically mention it

Comment: According to links from my answer try  to change naming conventions. ACMEMyBundleExtension to ACMEMyExtension and acme_my_bundle to acme_my. I think your extension is not loaded by Symfony for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Creating the `Configuration` class alone is not enough. You need to register a dependency injection extension and use the `Configuration` class in there.

Read more about in the [How to Create Friendly Configuration for a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html) cookbook:

> [The Configuration] class can now be used in your load() method to merge configurations and force validation (e.g. if an additional option was passed, an exception will be thrown)

```php
namespace Acme\MyBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class AcmeMyBundleExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();

        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Naming your extension class according to the convention will make it's automatically loaded. More on creating DIC extension classes in [Creating an Extension Class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#creating-an-extension-class). You can also enable the extension manually, see [Manually registering an extension class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#manually-registering-an-extension-class).

Comment: The `Extension` is defined, I have updated my question to specifically mention it

Comment: Fair enough. Verify your naming, or try to manually enable your extension: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#manually-registering-an-extension-class