# Validation doesn't work using Symfony2.8

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I am a newbie in using Symfony2.8 and I got a validation problem.

This is how my code from dependency injection looks like --

```
    <?php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $r = new \ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
        $dir = dirname($r->getFileName());

        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator($dir.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('validation.yml');
    }
}
```

And then I am trying to validate that those two columns are unique. (UniqueConstraint).

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
AppBundle\Entity\StaticContent:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
              fields: [build, name]
```

With StaticContent in the Entity and it complains that it can't find the StaticContent.

```
   nebo@localhost:/var/www/html/iclei$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql


  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                               
  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "AppBundle\Entity\StaticContent" (in /var/www/html/iclei/src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/validation.yml). Looked for nam  
  espace "AppBundle\Entity\StaticContent", found none
```

What am I doing wrong ? 
Also I have inside the

```
app/config/config.yml 

framework:
    #esi: ~
    #translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enabled: true, enable_annotations: true }
```

And this is the structure of the Bundle which we are building. 
**DIR**/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/StaticContent.orm.yml
**DIR**/src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php

This is my doctrine configuration:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    AppBundle: ~
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

On I13 request I add my entity.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * StaticContent
 */
class StaticContent
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $build;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $data;
```

With their getters and setters.

```
AppBundle\Entity\StaticContent:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\StaticContentRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 255
    data:
        type: blob
manyToOne:
    build:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Build
        inversedBy: staticContents
        joinColumn:
            name: build_id
            referencedColumnName: id
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: Did you check the StaticContent namespace, file and class name (including case and file extension) to put aside an autoloading fail on the entity ?

Comment: namespace AppBundle\Entity;

Comment: class StaticContent

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937442/symfony-container-has-no-extensions-when-loading-my-bundle

Comment: Can you post yml mapping too? (StaticContent.orm.yml)

Comment: Yeah, I have updated the question.

Comment: First thing that I see: Why your table name is null?

Comment: Do you have AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration file?

Comment: No, I don't have AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration file.

Comment: And this was build by someone else in the team and naively believed that it was built in the right way.

Comment: But still I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to enable bundle under doctrine configuration and tell is it works:

```
 # Doctrine Configuration
    doctrine:            
        dbal:
            driver: pdo_mysql
            host: '%database_host%'
            port: '%database_port%'
            dbname: '%database_name%'
            user: '%database_user%'
            password: '%database_password%'
            charset: UTF8
        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
            entity_managers:
                default:
                    auto_mapping: true                        
                    mappings:
                        YOURBundle: ~
```

Change AppExtension:

```
<?php

       namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;


class AppExtension extends Extension {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure if I understood you correctly. But know it doesn't work because it complains about the orm configuration.

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]  
  Unrecognized options "naming_strategy, auto_mapping" under "doctrine.orm"

Comment: Well it is set by default.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Just now I have seen that the default is in other color.

Comment: Still same issue.

Comment: Is it really that hard to put validation to work in the Symfony2.8 ? Or is this just my configuration that's screwed up ?

Comment: Try to remove enabled: validation: { enable_annotations: true }

Comment: Can you show me your entity (AppBundle\Entity\StaticContent)?

Comment: Do you want to continue this discussion at chat ? It would be easier.

Comment: <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * StaticContent
 */
class StaticContent
{

Comment: It looks like this ? Can You see anything ?